# Stylelint class ordering in vue

Tags: vue.js, sass, stylelint

I am configuring Stylelint for a Vue project and I want it so in `.vue` files in between the scss style tags the classes and other declarations are ordered alphabetically and based on their types.
So from this:

```
<style lang="scss">
.b {}
.c {}
.a {}
input {}
</style>
```

Lint to this:

```
<style>
input {}
.a {}
.b {}
.c {}
</style>
```

I could not find a solution online, the closest I found was Tailwind class ordering but it is not quiet like this.

I tried `stylelint-order` plugin but I didn't find the rule I need.

Comment: Does yours work with regular CSS already?

Comment: Nope, I did not find anything about ordering like this, no matter if it is css or scss.